# How to export a Node.js module requiring assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js

My case is that I need to require a module named Router in my index file meanwhile assign value to a variable of the module.

I have figured out several ways to achieve it. However, as a beginner, I want to know which one is the best practice or design and why cannot use the others.

**Method 1** - export a setter & keep variable as 'private'

router.js

```
var handler;
exports.setHandler=function(h){handler=h};
exports.route=function(){console.log(handler)}
```

index.js

```
var router=require('./router');
router.setHanlder('test');
router.route();
```

**Method 2** - let variable be 'public' and use 'this' to refer

router.js

```
exports.handler={}; //not necessary
exports.route=function(){console.log(this.handler)}
```

index.js

```
var router=require('./router');
router.hanlder='test';
router.route();
```

**Method 3** - export a factory function to receive value as a parameter

router.js

```
module.exports=function(handler){
  return {route:function(){console.log(return handler)}};
}
```

index.js

```
var router=require('./router')('test');
router.route();
```

Which one above should I use? Any other methods suggested?

Comment: It depends: If you require the module in multiple other modules, should each of them be able to use its own handler or will the handler be shared, and whoever sets the last handler wins?

Comment: @FelixKling actually, I wish each of them has its own handler and I think all my solutions work like this. How could you let them share one handler?

Comment: Option 1 and 2 only allows a single handler for all modules that require your module. Keep in mind that modules are on evaluated *once*, so whenever you change a local variable inside the module, or a property of the module, it will affect all callsites.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest method 3, it being a callback;non-blocking code. Also, it is close to what seems natural to me!

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it this way - I recommend trying to stay away from handlers like that with modules because it is a complexity trap that will catch you one day, that is, unless you need them =).

```
module.exports = function( options ) {
    // set options

    // based on options set vars and functions on this
    if (options.test === true) this.route = function() {//....}
    else this.route = function() {//......} 
}
```

then in the using file

```
var Router = require('router.js');

var router = new Router({/* options */});

router.route();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use method 2 as well. If you are using aws lambda, you will see that they used method 2 to export the function handler.